# Entire function with absolute value one in the boundary of the unit disc is a polynimial

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that

> If a nonconstant entire function $f$ is such that $|f(z)|=1$ when $|z|=1$, then $f=cz^m$ where $m$ is an positive integer and $c \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $|c|=1$.

Just before that problem I proved this:

> (*) If $f: \overline{\Delta}=\overline{\Delta}(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous nonconstant that is analytic in $\Delta = \Delta(0,1)$ and satisfies $|f(z)|=1$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$, prove that 
>   $$f(z) = c \prod_{k=1}^r \left( \dfrac{z-a_k}{1-\overline{a}_kz} \right)^{m_k}$$
>   for every $z \in \overline{\Delta}$, onde $a_1,a_2,...,a_r$ are distinct point in $\Delta$, $m_1,m_2,\ldots, m_r$ positive intergers and $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is such that $|c|=1$.

The only thing i'm sure is that $f$ has at least one zero in $\Delta(0,1)$. Using (*), i just need to prove that $f(0)=0$ is the only one zero of $f$ with multiplicity $m$, but I don't know how I do that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your formula, if any of the $a_k$ were non-zero, $f$ would have a pole at $1/\overline a_k$ contradicting it being entire.

Comment: I'm confuse with this thing: when we restrict f to the closed unit disc, then we can apply z in the formula just if z is in the closed unit disc. You say we will have a pole at $1/\overline{a}_k$,  but that number is out of the open disc and the formula is no applicable except on the boundary.

Comment: @DudaDuarte But your function is entire: it can't have poles anywhere, even outside the disc.